# How can I group by using the first character of the Last Name using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I am trying to answer this question for class and I am having a bit of trouble understanding why things do and don't work. The inquiry I have is about the use of LINQ and group by.

This is the question I am trying to complete

> : • "Students grouped by the first letter of their last name."

I am not getting errors the terminal results are just blank on my end. I do not understand why.

This is what I did

```
 using System;

using System.Linq;

using System.Collections.Generic;

                
public class Program
 {
         public static void Main()
   {
    // Student collection

    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 

            new Student {First="Bob", Last="Jones", ID=111, Age=15, Scores= 5},

            new Student {First="Bob", Last="Jones", ID=111, Age=15, Scores= 10},

            new Student {First="Claire", Last="Simpson", ID=112, Age=17, Scores= 5},

            new Student {First="John", Last="Feetham", ID=113, Age=21, Scores= 10},

            new Student {First="Jonathan", Last="Potts", ID=114, Age=10, Scores= 10},

            new Student {First="Pepe", Last="Garcia", ID=115, Age=20, Scores= 5},

            new Student {First="Samantha", Last="Fakhouri", ID=116, Age=17, Scores= 5},

            new Student {First="Roger", Last="Song", ID=117, Age=19, Scores= 5},

            new Student {First="Hugo", Last="Garcia", ID=118, Age=15, Scores= 10},

            new Student {First="Richard", Last="Ammerman", ID=119, Age=14, Scores= 10},

            new Student {First="Kevin", Last="Adamson", ID=120, Age=11, Scores= 10},

            new Student {First="Jeet", Last="Singh", ID=121, Age=12, Scores= 10}

        };
    
    var charList = studentList.Select(s => s.Last.First()).ToList();


  }
    
}

public class Student{

public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Scores { get; set;}

}
```

Comment: `var charList = studentList.GroupBy(e => e.Last[0]);`

Comment: You say your "results are just blank".  Are you expecting output?  You aren't sending anything to the terminal.  It's creating charList, but it's not doing anything with it.

Comment: where can i see the list ?

Answer (score 1):

You create a `List` and perform a `Select`. But you need to write the result of the output. That will solve your first problem, which is that the output is blank. About printing the results of a list: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-print-all-elements-of-a-list-in-c-sharp

Now, let's see your code:

```
var charList = studentList.Select(s => s.Last.First()).ToList();
```

Your `studentList` is selecting the first letters, but it does not group it.

You will need to call `.GroupBy(s => s.Last[])` on your `studentList`.